# Looping coefficient values for raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, loop

I am trying to loop through dbf files to obtain coefficient values using calculate tool and then insert in regression equation using raster calculator to make extrapolated maps. But so far I have managed to take out the coefficient values seperately but unable to use raster calulator for the purpose.

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Set the analysis environments
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/Mauro_points"

# Set local variables
dem_raster = Raster("D:/datasets/DEM ALTA_VALTELLINA LOMBARDY REGION/clip_dtm.tif")
print(type(dem_raster))

#looping through dbf files
for dbf_file in arcpy.ListFiles("*coefficient.dbf"):
    #print(dbf_file)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dbf_file, ["Coef"]) as cursor:
        values = sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})
       # print(values[0] , values[1])
        #print(type(values[0]))
        ##Execute RasterCalculator function
        output_raster = RasterCalculator(dem_raster, [values[0], values[1]], "values[0] * dem_raster + values[1]", "FirstOf", 
                                         "FirstOf")
        
        # Save the output
        output_raster.save("D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/Mauro_points/try1.tif")
```

It shows an error of

`RuntimeError: Failed to apply Raster Function: 'RasterCalculator' (The parameter is incorrect.  Parameter 'Rasters' is missing or invalid. Bind failed in function 'Raster Calculator Function' [Raster Calculator Function].)`

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications but this sounds like two questions which means it may be closed for lacking focus.  Please always present code as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: I dont have Spatial Analyst so I cant test this but what you are trying to do with  `"values[0] * dem_raster + values[1]"` should probably be `"{0}*{1}+{2}".format(values[0], dem_raster, values[1])`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Bera. Based on what I understood  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm, the solution you have mentioned is for the case when all inputs used in raster calculator are present in the field within the dbf files. But because I added the raster image seperately it cannot be a solution. Plus it still shows me the same error after your suggestion.

Comment: `"values[0] * dem_raster + values[1]"` is definitly wrong. Probably something more that's incorrect

Comment: While doing the same process using model builder it accepts the expression, but why is it creating an issue in arcpy notebook.